# My data isnt being saved to database and im not getting an error

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

Im having an issue where this code just executes and the vardump shows the var i put in the text field but theres no data showing up in the database, theres also no error showing up

view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
       <body>
           <div>
               <form method="post" action="/post">
                   {{ csrf_field() }}
                   <input type="text" name="email">
                   <input type="text" name="password">
                   <input type="submit" name="submit">
               </form>
           </div>
       </body>        
    </head>
</html>
```

controller:

```
  <?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\werknemer_model;

    class werknemer extends Controller
    {
        /*Show the form for creating a new resource.*/
        public function create(Request $request)
        {
            $email = $request->input('email');
            var_dump($email);
            $werknemer = new werknemer();
            $werknemer->store($request);
            return view('login_portal');
        }
    }
```

model:

```
<?php

    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\controllers\werknemer
    class werknemer_model extends Model
    {
        public function store (Request $request){
            $email = $request->input('email');
            $password = $request->input('password');

            $werknemer = new werknemer;
            $werknemer->id = 1;
            $werknemer->bedrijf_id = 1;
            $werknemer->email = $email;
            $werknemer->naam = $password;
            $werknemer->save();
        try {
            DB::connection()->getPdo();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        die("Could not connect to the database.  Please check your configuration.");
        }
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('Login_portal');
    });
    Route::post('/post','werknemer@create');
```

Question : **My data isnt being saved to database and im not getting an error**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common problem, easy to forgot. You forgot to set variable in your model (for Mass Assignment). Check what data you want to put to database and set it in your model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'another_data', 'another_variable'];
}
```

And as far as I see, your model structure is not going along the Laravel convention. Read it and save time in future: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment